# Global Transaction with Teradata

Tags: java, transactions, teradata, spring-transactions, xa

I am using **Oracle** and **Teradata** both databases in my Java based project. I want to setup global transaction so that I can perform operations on both the Database under one transaction.

For global transactions such as JTA or atomikos database must have XA driver support. But as my findings Teradata doesn't have XA driver.

So now how could I setup the global transaction and performance operations on both database under 1 transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why would you want to do that?

If you use terradata as a data warehouse, you could feed it in a separate, asynchronous process.

That being said, you don't strictly need an XA driver to run as part of a JTA transaction. Of course, not doing so leads you to make some compromise, especially in case of recovery.

All JTA-aware transaction managers I know have the notion of *Last Resource Commit* (or LRC, [check this page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/LastResourceCommit) for more details). You could configure your Teradata datasource as LRC.

### Resources

- [Bitronix config](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/LastResourceCommit)
- [Atomikos config](http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/NonXaDataSource)

Answer (score 0):

If you use oracle and the teradata database, you need to configure the oracle database gateway to support distributed transactions. In that you will not use XA, but you will use distributed transactions with two-phase commit.